# Our application used PayTM for payment transaction

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payment, paytm

Our application used Pay TM for payment transaction, when student purchase digital e-course.
So currently our app new version upload on google play console. At that time google play console team reject our application. And display below errors.

=> Your app uses a non-Google Play’s billing system to accept payment for access to in-app features or services, including any app functionality, digital content or goods (collectively “in-app purchases”).

Answer (score 0):

Ref: [Google Payment Guidelines](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9858738?hl=en)

Courses unfortunately comes under digital content according to web hence as shown in this [article](https://www.digit.in/news/general/google-plays-billing-system-will-be-compulsory-for-in-app-purchases-from-september-2021-56644.html)

> Google has announced that all the apps that sell digital content through the Play Store will have to use Google Play's billing system and Google will charge a fixed percentage fee for every purchase made on that app. On September 18, Google blocked the Paytm app on Play Store for violating its policy on sports betting activities.